# Как правильно расставить знаки при перечислении?

Tags: пунктуация

> Учитель математики, информатики, труда, - Петр Иванович Курочка.

Как правильно в этом случае поставить знаки препинания и почему (если знаете)?

Answer (score 2):

Постановка знаков препинания зависит от контекста. Если вы хотите представить учителя, вы говорите: "Знакомьтесь, учитель математики Петр Иванович Курочка". В данном случае "учитель математики" — определение, а точнее говоря — согласованное приложение, оно называет тот же предмет другим именем, в данном случае обозначает профессию Петра Ивановича. Если вы отвечаете на вопрос, как зовут учителя математики (кто является учителем математики), то говорите:  "Учитель математики — Петр Иванович Курочка" (здесь ставится тире). В последнем случае можно добавить слово *это* (Учитель математики — это Петр Иванович Курочка). Здесь "учитель математики" — подлежащее, а "Петр Иванович Курочка" — сказуемое.

Между однородными членами предложения в отсутствие союзов ставится запятая. При перечислении перед последним однородным членом обычно ставят союз *и* — для благозвучия. После последнего однородного члена запятая не ставится.

Таким образом, есть два варианта, выбирайте один из них в зависимости от контекста:

**Учитель математики, информатики и труда Петр Иванович Курочка.**

**Учитель математики, информатики и труда — Петр Иванович Курочка.**